# How to start WifiSetupActivity?

Tags: android

I want setup wifi when I fisrt enter the system, so I find a activity named WifiSetupActivity in Setting. I try to start this Activity, but failed, and logcat shows

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSetupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Don't start activity explicitly. Set the action instead.

Comment: No,  it's still failed